# How to get this simple jQuery to work?

Tags: jquery

I'm pretty new to jQuery. I'm trying to create a photo wall where the images will start to fade in one after another as the page loads. Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="photoWall">
   <a href=""><img src="a.jpg" /></a>
   <a href=""><img src="b.jpg" /></a>
   <a href=""><img src="c.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

and the failed jQuery:

```
$('#photoWall a').hide();
$('#photoWall a:eq(0)').fadeIn();
if ($('#photoWall a:before:visible')) {
    $(this).fadeIn();
}
```

My logic is, hide all links containing the images at first. Then fadein the 1st link, next check to see if the previous link is visible, if so fade in the current link, and so on until all links are showing. How to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [There is no `:before` selector.](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- Any code that runs after an animation, such as the `.fadeIn()` after the `.fadeOut()`, needs to happen in a callback.
- There's no loop here, so it's only going to fade in the first and second images.

This is fancier looking than what you've got, but it's not too bad:

```
$(function ()
{
    function show($links, i)
    {
        var $link = $links.eq(i);
        if ( !$link.length ) return;
        $link.fadeIn(function ()
        {
            show($links, ++i);
        });
    }

    show($('#photoWall a').hide(), 0);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/ECWxM/

Comment: `$links.get(i).fadeIn(...` That wouldn't seem to work. I imagine you meant to use `.eq()`.

Comment: @Matt Ball: Oops... Looks like you've got 2 other issues. First `if (!$link) return;` should be `if (!$link.length) return;`. Not a big deal since the callback won't happen anyway, because there's nothing to fade in. The more serious one is that you're getting a `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` because you used the post-incrementing operator `i++` instead of pre `++i`. When the call stack limit is reached, the exception is thrown, and apparently allows the `i` to be incremented and passed to the recursive call, at which point you get the error again, and so on. ;o)

Comment: ...changed it for you. Was afraid the other guy would start whining about accepted answers again.

Answer (score 2):

```
function fadethem(elem) {
    elem.fadeIn('slow', function() {
        if (elem.next().length > 0) fadethem(elem.next());
    });
}

fadethem($('#photoWall a:eq(0)'));
```

Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QFccn/1/

I've hidden the images on pageload using CSS in stead of javascript. Otherwise the images would be displayed until the DOM is ready.

On page load I call the fade function with the first image.

If animation is finished (callback of `fadeIn()`) I call the function again with next element (if there are more).

Comment: (+1) this is a much more concise solution than mine.

Comment: @Matt Ball: Thanks. Too bad for others OP didn't mark it as answer :D

Comment: I'm sure they'll survive without your answer being on top.

Answer (score 0):

This becomes super easy when you use the [`delay()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) method.

```
$('#photoWall a').hide().each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(i * 400).fadeIn();
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/eRgPt/ *(Borrowing the fiddle from [@Matt Ball](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139010/matt-ball).)*

---

**EDIT:**

To explain (so the down-voter can understand), it's really simple.

Using the [`each()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method , you can operate on each element that matched the selector individually.

You also get an *index* argument that is passed to the callback. So all this does is it multiplies the current index by the total length of the animation, making each consecutive element begin *n* milliseconds later than the previous.

```
   0 * 400 = 0
   1 * 400 = 400
   2 * 400 = 800
   3 * 400 = 1200
```

---

Additionally, you could easily assign the duration of the animation to a variable in order to change both the duration of the animation and the delay.

```
var duration = 1000;

$('#photoWall a').hide().each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(i * duration).fadeIn(duration);
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/eRgPt/1/

Comment: @Down-voter: Hello? What, you can't come up with a reason? No surprise.

Comment: I like this variation as well. These 3 answers more-or-less cover all the basic ways to do it.